# Unable to export dicom file from GCP dicom store to storage with original filename

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-healthcare

I am trying to export dicom file (.dcm) after de-identification from dicom store to GCS bucket. Once the operation is successful, the image gets loaded in gcs bucket but the file name is in numerical format. Is there any way to export the file with original file name.

For example :

**source dicom filename :** source.dcm 

**exported dicom filename :**1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.5.1.285203166265972638872377502038110961072/1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.5.1.12890303936119703509451462489773813927/1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.5.1.216682955412074535971523503539344066890.png

I want to destination filename same as source filename for easy identification and further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The export operation always stores the image in the folder: studyUID/seriesUID/instanceUID of the DICOM file that you are exporting. Only the contents of the DICOM file that is imported/stored in the Healthcare API is stored. The name of the file is not really a part of the dicom file ie it is not part of the contents and hence is not stored in the API.

Comment: what if I have 5 source images and after exporting I will be having 5 images with some different name. Then how can I map the pre and post images one to one?

Comment: If you have 5 images: 
img1: study1/series1/instance1
img2: study1/series1/instance2
img3: study1/series1/instance3
img4: study1/series1/instance4
img5: study1/series1/instance5

They will be stored in the new Dataset according to their UIDs - so you can map img1 to the new file: study1/series1/instance1

Comment: /{study_id}/{series_id}/{instance_id} is auto-generated for every image. How can customize them according to my need. Requesting you to provide an example on this.

Comment: You can view the study_uid, series_uid and instance uid using tool like dcmdump (https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdump.html). Usage: dcmdump <filename>
If you want to modify tags like UIDs you can use dcmodify(https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmodify.html) 
For example: 
To modify StudyInstanceUID to study1: dcmodify -m "(0020,000D)=study_1" <file name>
To modify SeriesInstanceUID to series1: dcmodify -m "(0020,000E)=series_1 <file_name>
To modify SOPInstanceUID to instance1:  dcmodify -m "(0008,0018)=instance_1" <filename>
Tags reference: https://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/dicom-tags/